# Why I can not install Ubuntu on my laptop?

Tags: installation

I've tried to install Ubuntu 11.04 and 12.04, but I have the same problem on both.

I proceed like this: I restart my computer, the language menu shows and I select my language, and then select to set up Ubuntu.
Then I get a black page, and nothing else.

I have an ATI graphics card. My laptop is an HP G62 series.

What should I do to make the install work?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ubuntu, but the first thing I'd do is to determine if the system really hanged or is it just an error related i.e. to missing drivers on the installation CD. When you see the black screen, do Alt+F1 - F6 keys work? (after pressing the key combination, you should see the console output of Ubuntu). If yes, do you see any error message on the screen? You could check some other Linux distribution and see if the problem is the Ubuntu installation CD.

Answer (score 0):

Try the text based installer found [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads)